# How to change output filename if it originally is something else

Tags: bash, filenames

I have two files with different names. I have a for-loop to see if one file is there; if it is then it will change a file.

My first thought was to make a list of all the files and what its counterpart is. That would not look nice and I can't cover all possibilities in the script. If this is the only way, how would I do it best?

The script will find if a program has an icon on the desktop. If it has then my script will change the size of that with ImageMagick. My problem is that the name of the program not always is the same as the icon-file. So I am not sure what the best action would be...

I need the "rtcom-call-ui.desktop" to be paired with "general_call.png" so it can be found with my script. The script can't find "general_call.png" cause it is looking for "rtcom-call-ui.png".

```
for applet in $appletDir*
do
    app=`basename $applet | sed -e 's/.*://g' -e 's/.*osso-//g' -e 's/\.desktop.*//g'`
    find=`find $icoDir64 $icoDirSca | grep .png` 

    for file in $find
    do
        base="`basename ${file}`"

        if [ "${base}" = "${app}.png" -o "${base}" = "tasklaunch_${app}.png" -o "${base}" = "general_${app}.png" ]; then
            echo "WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! $file" 
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are tyring to do exactly ..at least to me... please try to rephrase your question. Or post some code.

Comment: It's as below.. i added my code hope it helps explain little more.

Comment: I'm not convinced you should be messing with other programs' icons.  Would the best way of operating be to read the description of the program that identifies the icon files it uses?

Comment: I don't understand exactly Jonathan. How would i do that?

Comment: You should use `find -name "*.png"` instead of using `grep` and you should pipe `find` into `while read` instead of using `for`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis! I am just beginning learning how to script. ;)

Answer (score 0):

On gnome, a desktop launcher is a `.desktop` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=GIMP Image Editor
GenericName=Image Editor
Comment=Create images and edit photographs
Exec=gimp-2.6 %U
TryExec=gimp-2.6
Icon=gimp
Terminal=false
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;GTK;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=GIMP
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=General
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.6.7
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=gimp-2.6
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=application/postscript;application/pdf;image/bmp;image/g3fax;image/gif;image/x-fits;image/pcx;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/x-psd;image/x-sgi;image/x-tga;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-xwindowdump;image/x-xcf;image/x-compressed-xcf;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/x-psd;image/png;image/x-icon;image/x-xpixmap;image/svg+xml;image/x-wmf;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gimp20
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gimp20
```

that's a sample, GIMP launcher, is it the type of icon you are having? if it is you can inspect file content to get access to the executable name and icon filename.

Comment: It's not for Gnome but Maemo. I have not been able to find a file like that.